# display: inline-block; not working, I want to have a box next to an image, but it goes below

Tags: html, css, display

I want this image to go next to the box, and not below.

I tried using display: inline-block; but it didn't work. I also tried using float, but that did not work either. So I don't really know what to do here.

```css
.text {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.generic_chemco {
    margin-bottom: 2000px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1><i>Sketchless Chem</i></h1>
</div>

<div class="text">
    <p>
        <h1>Our mission</h1>
        Our mission here at Sketchless Chem .co is 
        to provide the best customer service and 
        provide to the every need of our clients,
        as well as make the best, most high 
        quality chemicals we know how to make.
        This is very important to us, and our workers
        agree. We use state of the art chemical purification
        methods, and have a specialised 3 stage testing method.
        This makes our chemicals truly state of the art.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="chemco.png" class="generic_chemco">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code it seemed like the image and the box were indeed side-by-side. So I guess what you're really after is vertical alignment between the two objects. For that you may want to defer to Flexbox:

```css
.text {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}


.flexy {
  display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1><i>Sketchless Chem</i></h1>
</div>

<div class="flexy">
  <div class="text">
      <p>
          <h1>Our mission</h1>
          Our mission here at Sketchless Chem .co is 
          to provide the best customer service and 
          provide to the every need of our clients,
          as well as make the best, most high 
          quality chemicals we know how to make.
          This is very important to us, and our workers
          agree. We use state of the art chemical purification
          methods, and have a specialised 3 stage testing method.
          This makes our chemicals truly state of the art.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
      <img src="chemco.png" class="generic_chemco" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a good resource for what `display:flex` can do: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/